# Docker build failed on Windows 10 Pro x64

Tags: python, docker, windows-10

I have like this docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8.2-alpine
MAINTAINER Developer Apps LTD

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

> **Note:** This code work on **MAC OS** perfectly but on **Windows 10 Pro x64** not work.

When I build this code using docker then get **error**:

> The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /requirements.txt' returned a
>   non-zero code: 4294967295: failed to shutdown container: container
>   c96f2e9d16b198eaf12f1402be68c9103904726814ac02bb2dd31d1b60b18b5e
>   encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure
>   in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the
>   specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): subsequent
>   terminate failed container
>   c96f2e9d16b198eaf12f1402be68c9103904726814ac02bb2dd31d1b60b18b5e
>   encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure
>   in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the
>   specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)

**Here is screenshot**:

[image]

**Docker version:**

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:37:20 2020
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem building Docker images that are Linux-based when you have Docker in "Windows Container" mode. I'm seeing similar issues

Comment: Yes you're right @DavidGardiner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been reported at https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/issues/813

In [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/sferquel/status/1253606403392102400?s=20), Simon Ferquel (Software Engineer at Docker) said:

> This will probably get fixed in a windows update patch (the issue is fixed in insider fast builds). Once it is fixed, we plan to better support running both daemons at the same time and leverage docker contexts to allow using both wincontainers and wsl2 at the same time.